# "invalid cast from type 'const myClass' to type 'int'", how can I make it valid?

Tags: c++, eclipse, casting, typecast-operator

I am getting an error about the return statement (or cast) in the final function in the following extract from a library header

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// class __HashMapDefaultProviderT

/**
* @internal
* @class    __HashMapDefaultProviderT
* @brief    This is an implementation of the IHashCodeProviderT interface for the HashMap class.
* @since    1.0
*/
template<class KeyType>
class __HashMapDefaultProviderT
    :   public IHashCodeProviderT<KeyType>,
    public Object
{
public:

    // Lifecycle

    /**
    * This is the default constructor for this class.
    *
    * @since     1.0
    */
    __HashMapDefaultProviderT(void) {}


    /**
    * This is the destructor for this class.
    *
    * @since     1.0
    */
    virtual ~__HashMapDefaultProviderT(void) {}


    // Operation

    /**
    * Gets the hash code of the specified object
    *
    * @since        1.0
    * @return       The hash code of the specified object
    * @see          Osp::Base::Object::GetHashCode
    */
    int GetHashCode(const KeyType& obj) const
    {
        return (int)obj;
    }


};
```

the error is:

> invalid cast from type 'const myClass' to type 'int'

What is the fix for this? The header file is called [FBaseColHashMapT.h](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/FBaseColHashMapT_8h.html)

I've added `operator>` and `operator<` methods already but I don't know how else to get my class to hash or how to permit the cast that is required above, short of inheriting it, but I'd like to see if I can avoid that. To support those two operators I wrote:

```
inline int GetHashCode() const {return myIntMember/4 + clientRect.GetHashCode();}
```

Maybe it could be of re-use again here?

I am supplying `myClass` as the key to this template class and `int` as the value.

Comment: You are using reserved names everywhere.  This architecture also looks like Java, not good C++ design.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I am trying to pass `myClass`, which is slowly gathering members but needs to be kept lightweight, as the key to the parameterised template class. It could cope with inheriting from `Object` which prolly defines that cast, but I would like to provide that cast'ability myself so I can avoid inheriting from `Object` on smaller, more performance critical classes.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the reserved names are part of the libarary (without GetHashCode I still got this error, I will rename it... nope same problem). Where else am I using reserved names by choice that are not those supplied by the library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously the class expects the `KeyType` (in your case `myDescriptor`) to be convertible to `int`. Therefore the fix would be to add that conversion to `myDescriptor`:

```
class myDescriptor
{
public:
  operator int() const { return (whatever the library expects, probably a hash key); }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Just a quick note that the `const` is really important here! I left it off in my code and couldn't figure out why in the world GCC was still complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Either your class needs to provide a conversion to int:

```
myClass::operator int() const {
    return myIntMember/4 + clientRect.GetHashCode();
}
```

...or you need to specialise the hashmap class's `GetHashCode()` member function (You would do this in myClass's header, but in the hashmap's namespace):

```
template<class KeyType>
inline int __HashMapDefaultProviderT::GetHashCode(const myClass& obj) const {
    return obj.myIntMember/4 + obj.clientRect.GetHashCode();
}
```

I'm not familiar with bada, so I can't say which is the expected approach. Both are kind of loopy, though.